# Is using an intermediate table to manage multiple exclusive relation a good idea?

Tags: c#, sql, .net-core, entity-framework-core, lazy-loading

For a project, I need to be able to generate tasks who are related to different types of ressources. In order to implement, I'm using foreign keys in my main "Tasks" table which are exclusive to each other which means that only one key is possible at a time and all others must be *NULL*.

For example, I have my "Tasks" table linked to 2 tables : "TableA","TableB".
If it happens that my new task is linked to a TableA record, then I set the foreign key in "Tasks" table in order to join to "TableA" and I make sure that "TableB" key field stays NULL.

[image]

However, when I'm using EF Core (+ Lazy Loading), I noticed that some data couldn't be retrieved despite the Foreign Key column is filled.

I came to the conclusion that the implementation was incorrect and givers to EF Core some trouble to load the data. Has anyone have an idea if there could be a better way to handle that sort of relationship ?

Comment: If its many to many relation, then it is impossible to do it with out junction or intermediate table

Comment: Why `table_B_id` is `date`?

Comment: @Arvo Sorry typo error but indeed it is supposed to be a int value